# Dynamic Systems Practice Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I'm a student in physics and I was wondering how I would go about solving for tension for both string A(left) and string B(right). Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: Free-body diagrams are your friends! You will need 3 of them.

Answer (score -1):

There are three unknowns - the tensions in strings A and B and the acceleration $a$ of the blocks (note that all three blocks have the same acceleration).

If you consider the forces acting on each block separately and apply Newton’s second law, you will get three equations - for example, the forces acting on the left hand block are its weight $4g$ and the tension $T_A$ in string A, so you have

$4g - T_A = 4a$

(Don’t forget to include friction acting on the middle block).

From these three equations you can find the values of the three unknowns.

Comment: I was able to get the acceleration (2.31m/s^2) and used that to find the tensions of both strings (9.24N --> Left, 4.62 --> Right). Could you please explain why the tension forces are different?

Comment: @EshanJoshi Why do you expect the tensions in the two strings to be equal ? If they were equal then the net force on the middle block would be zero and it would not accelerate ! By the way, your values for the tensions are wrong - you have calculated the net force on the left and right hand blocks but don’t forget each block is acted on by its weight as well as a string tension.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. Am I now supposed to set up the equation like F(NetA) = 9.42N = Fg - FT and F(NetB) = 4.62N = Fg - FT to solve for the tensions?

Comment: @EshanJoshi Use Newton’s second law to set up an equation for the left hand block. Now that you have a value for $a$ the only unknown in that equation is the tension in the left hand string. Rearrange the equation to find that tension. Do the same for the right hand block - but remember this block is accelerating upwards, not downwards.